# PDO bindParam right way?

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Hey a quick little question.

What is the better or safest way to bind parameters, values and columns?
i'v seen these two ways to do it, but i can't figure out what the difference is?

with :email and the `:email`, `$email`

```
$stmt = $db->prepare( "SELECT `email` FROM `users` WHERE `email` = :email");
        $stmt->bindValue( ':email', $email );
```

Or the questionmark ?

```
$stmt = $db->prepare( "SELECT `email` FROM `users` WHERE `email` = :?");
        $stmt->bindValue( 1, $email );
```

Comment: if you use first method (:email ... ) you can detect & separate param in big queries. there is not any difference between them.

Comment: There is no difference. First one uses name placeholder and second one using question mark placeholder. both are equally safe.

Comment: there shouldn't be a colon for the `?` placeholder. However, PDO uses both `:var` and `?` placeholders, while `mysqli_` can only use `?`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No difference but only advantage it is more readable.

`mysqli` only has `?` which is not as nice to read when you got too many parameters

Imagine something like this:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare( "Call store_procedure ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?");
```

it could be so much more error prone and hard to debug

Answer (score 2):

They are both equally valid ways (however, your second example has a colon before the question mark which shouldn't be there). The first example is more readable. With the second example, if you decide to change your SQL statement later on, you may have to re-number everything.

So, if you originally had this:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `users` (`fname`, `lname`, `address`, `email`) values (?, ?, ?, ?)");
    $stmt->bindValue( 1, $fname );
    $stmt->bindValue( 2, $lname );
    $stmt->bindValue( 3, $address );
    $stmt->bindValue( 4, $email );
```

and wanted to insert a middle initial. You could insert it at the end, but for readability, you'd likely put it in between the first and last names and would have to renumber your code as follows:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `users` (`fname`, `initial`, `lname`, `address`, `email`) values (?, ?, ?, ?)");
    $stmt->bindValue( 1, $fname );
    $stmt->bindValue( 2, $initial );
    $stmt->bindValue( 3, $lname );
    $stmt->bindValue( 4, $address );
    $stmt->bindValue( 5, $email );
```

It just makes things a bit less readable and a bit more tedious to fix. The only benefit I can see with the question mark method is less typing, but in the long run it's better without. Also, when inserting and moving things around it's easier to make a mistake without spotting it. For example, you might accidentally have placed the initial in the wrong spot as follows:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `users` (`fname`, `initial`, `lname`, `address`, `email`) values (?, ?, ?, ?)");
    $stmt->bindValue( 1, $fname );
    $stmt->bindValue( 2, $lname );
    $stmt->bindValue( 3, $initial );
    $stmt->bindValue( 4, $address );
    $stmt->bindValue( 5, $email );
```

Your code wouldn't realize this isn't what you wanted to do and it will try putting the last name in the initial column and the inital in the last name column. Using the named parameter method you wouldn't have this problem.